# Stop Cisco AnyConnect VPN from command line in Mac

Tags: macos

I need to automatically stop my Cisco AnyConnect VPN in Mac once some condition met (like the time of the day). Since there is not such a feature in the Cisco AnyConnect itself, one way for doing that would be using the command line to kill the corresponding process.

I got the corresponding process and tried to stop them by `sudo ps -ef | grep cisco | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`, but it did not help and new processes started instantly.

Any idea?